# Excel - average of range doing vlookup of that range inside the formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have 2 tables: Ratings List- A1:A8; Rating Lookup- C1:D6.

I would like to calculate the average rating of the *Ratings* table based on the value of the rating in the *Rating Lookup* table.

I could do this creating an extra column in the *Ratings* table doing a lookup of the *Rating Lookup* table, but I'd like to know if there was a way to automatically calculate the average without adding any extra column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try in `G2`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C2:C6=TRANSPOSE(A2:A8))*(D2:D6))/8
```

If one has Excel O365:

```
=SUM(VLOOKUP(A2:A8,C2:D6,2,0))/8
```

Comment: The first one works substituing the 8 by a 7, thanks. Using a *COUNTA(Ratings_List)* instead of manually inputting number of values gets me to the solution I wanted. Thank you very much.



*{=SUMPRODUCT((Rating_Lookup[Level]=TRANSPOSE(Rating_List[Ratings]))*(Rating_Lookup[Rating]))/COUNTA(Rating_List[Ratings])}*

Comment: Obviously it's seven. Miscounted =). Glad it works @Wryfyng. Have a look at the other answer too. It's (to me at least) more sound because of less calculations.

Answer (score 1):

`MATCH` will return an array if `lookup_value` is an array. So you can try:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(Ratings_Lookup,MATCH(Ratings_List,Ratings_Lookup[Level],0),2))
```

[image]

Here is an example of `MATCH` returning an array in a version of Excel with dynamic arrays.  This is in O365:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, inputting an array in the _lookup value_ for _Match_ is not working for me. The result is not the desired one, and with _evaluate formula_ I see it's only getting the the first value of the array.



Checked the Match Function reference in support.microsoft and it doesn't say that the _lookup value_ can be an array "_The lookup_value argument can be a value (number, text, or logical value) or a cell reference to a number, text, or logical value._"

Comment: @Wryfyng Obviously, from the answer in the screenshot, it is working here.  Did you try entering it with `ctrl+shift+enter`?  What version of Excel?

Comment: Microsoft Excel 2016 (16.0.5095.1000). And yes, I tried both as normal formula and array formula.

Comment: @Wryfyng I edited my post to show `MATCH` returning an array. Perhaps it is only in O365 and not 2016.